# Nuxt.js transpilation into CommonJs when build

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, babel-loader

I'm creating vue application with nuxt.js (universal mode).
`nuxt build` command runs correctly and create `.nuxt` folder in project.
i dont want run it locally because `nuxt start` is ok. i need run on a window server with **urlRewrite** & **iisnode**.
when i run `server.js` in `.nuxt` served folder with `node server.js`, the exception accured:

> same as `node .nuxt/server.js` in local

```
import { stringify } from 'querystring'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    ...
```

I know the problem is because of **esm module import/export** that doesn't support by node.js. i want transpile into commonJs when building project. (`require and module.exports`).

**for example:**
**`server.js` in `.nuxt` folder** (created with `build`)

[image: exm module]

**must be:**
[image]

> node: 10.15.3
>   npm: 6.8.0
>   vue-cli: 3.8.2

i did some ways with `nuxt.config.js` build option configuration and doesnt resolved.

how can i do that? What's wrong?

**[example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-js-build-commonjs-itkz2)**

Comment: You shouldnt run nuxt with node .nuxt/server.js
you should run  it with nuxt command

Comment: i think this is wrong, because projects must run on server, for example hosting on win server with **urlRewrite** & **iisnode**. `server.js` in a `.nuxt` folder folder run with node and the same problem happens.

Comment: no, its not wrong. You shouldn't touch or launch anything in .nuxt directly ever. You should use either nuxt binary to launch or a custom launcher js file that u write yourself where u instantiate nuxt etc. or node node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt

Comment: ok, if i understand correctly, means that i need put some packages in `node_modules` next to the `.nuxt` folder in server, like `nuxt`, `express` etc. every package has dependency, probably i will have to put all projects package...!?

Comment: thx [Aldarund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239354/aldarund)  for your comments, but I think there's a better way

Comment: i dont really understand what you mean. Your node modules should be from your package.json and thats all. You dont need to put anything manually anywhere

Comment: you say that i need define launcher like `node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt` for launching on server. this launchers doesnt need any modules? can you send me a example via link?

Comment: It need only the modules that is from your package.json. And yes, to launch nuxt you need to have node_modules on your server.